# non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

```js
class Calisan:
    counter = 0
    zam_orani = 0.0

    def __init__(self, isim, soyisim, maas):  # constructor
        self.isim = isim
        self.soyisim = soyisim
        self.maas = maas
        self.email = isim + soyisim + "@asd.com"



        Calisan.counter = Calisan.counter + 1

    def giveNameSurname(self):
        return self.isim + " " + self.soyisim

    def zam_yap(self):
        self.maas = self.maas + self.maas * self.zam_orani
kisi = Calisan(input("İsim:"),input("Soyad:"),input("Maaş:"))
print("CEO:",kisi.isim,kisi.soyisim,"\nMail:",kisi.email,"\nMaaş:",kisi.maas)
Hosgeldiniz = "Sisteme Hoşgeldiniz efendim,toplam çalışan sayınız {}'dir ".format(Calisan.counter)
print(Hosgeldiniz)
Calisan.zam_orani = float(input("Zam oranını giriniz:"))
kisi.zam_yap()
print("Zamlı Maaş:",kisi.maas)
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CaHeD/Desktop/Python/veriable/zamoranı.py", line 28, in <module>
    kisi.zam_yap()
  File "C:/Users/CaHeD/Desktop/Python/veriable/zamoranı.py", line 22, in zam_yap
    self.maas = self.maas + self.maas * self.zam_orani
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: You can't multiply a string by a float.  What would `"abc" * 1.5` mean?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: One of them is a string. Try this: `"hi"*2` and then try `"hi"*2.2`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh `"abcal"`.

Answer (score 2):

All inputs are string in python, therefore you need to change it to float or integer. Change end of input line with float(input("Maas:"))

Comment: Thank you very, very much :)

Comment: @hizirplay Please look here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can multiply a sequence (e.g. a list `[]` or a `str`) by an integer (round number) to duplicate the elements in the sequence. For example:

```
>>> l = 'abc'
>>> l * 3
'abcabcabc'
```

You *can't* multiply a sequence by a non-round number, e.g. `1.5`:

```
>>> l = 'abc'
>>> l * 1.5
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

In your code you multiply your string `self.maas` by `self.zam_orani` which is 0.0, a `float`. To multiply by this number you would need to convert it to an `int`

```
>>> l = 'abc'
>>> l * int(1.5)  # int(1.5) = 1
'abc'
```

Alternatively, if your inputs are intended to all be numeric (i.e. you want to enter two numbers and get the product) you can convert them to floats before calculating, e.g.

```
>>> a = '0.5'
>>> b = '1.3'
>>> float(a) * float(b)
0.65
```

Comment: No problem :) No idea why the downvotes, I think I answered the question.